# Can electric charge/electromagnetics effects of stars, particles, etc., be a major factor in motions attributed to Dark Matter/Dark Energy?

Tags: electromagnetism, dark-matter, galaxies, dark-energy

Electromagnetic effects of moving charged stars and particle flux on galaxies rotation and space expansion.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Note that because the fundamental strength of the electromagnetic interaction is so very much larger than that of gravity, even a tiny charge imbalance would swamp out gravitational effects and leave us with a universe whose structure would look very different from what we see.

As far as we can tell, charge is conserved throughout the universe and the universe carries no net charge differences locally (that is, planets, stars, galaxies, galaxy clusters and superclusters are all electrically neutral).